# How I can get possible length of hypotenuse from one cathet?(pythagorean triples)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is some code, but i have mistake

```
import math
from itertools import combinations

p = int(input("Enter a number"))


squares = [i**2 for i in range(2, 1001)]
for y, x, z in combinations(squares, 3) :
    if y == p and z == math.sqrt((i * i) + (x * x)):
        print(z)
```

Comment: why you say you have a mistake?

Comment: What is the mistake?

Comment: does not output an answer

Answer (score 1):

My guess is because your line `math.sqrt((i * i) + (x * x))` should read `math.sqrt((y * y) + (x * x))`.

`i` is no longer a valid reference to anything really, just the residual value of the previous `for` loop.

Side note: You should probably provide a sample input and your expected and actual output for us to debug a bit better next time :)